# how to change color codes for different themes from a single base theme

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a base design and there are other designs which are same as base design theme but their color are different, I want to use same base design but need to change their color codes when user hits different url.

Example suppose I have a base theme loaded at base.theme.com
then I have one more theme with same structure but colors are different and it is hosted at url theme1.base.com, similarly I have

```
theme2.base.com
theme3base.com
theme4.base.com
and so on...
```

what I want is I dont want to write different css for each theme rather I want to change color codes according to the theme loaded.

Here is sample example to demonstrate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .header-bar{
            background: black;
        }
        .navbar-brand{
            color:white;
        }
        .section .panel-title{
            color: green;
        }
        .data-desc{
            color: gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default header-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="panel panel-default section">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="data-desc">random data</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default section">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="data-desc">my random data</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default section">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="data-desc">my random data</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now how do I change color codes for title, navbar bg and description for different urls. Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Here is a [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ck1qw7bu/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck1qw7bu/1/)

```
/* script - run on load and set the hostname to the body as an attribute */
(function(b) {
  b.setAttribute('data-host', location.hostname);
})(document.body);


/* CSS - overrides the default on selected hosts */
body[data-host='fiddle.jshell.net'] .section .panel-title {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem or may be I am stated wrong, but thats just a example, I have many classes and ids for my theme and the theme is too big, i have just given one exmple to understand problem. can we do anything like sccs? but I am not aware of that

Comment: There is nothing like that I will have same classes and ids as my domain name, can you tell me how to use scss for this ?

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere My answer is one way, now obviously not suitable in your case, and as I don't use SCSS myself I can't add a sample using it ... but someone that knows will likely provide one :)